# Pulumi - Creating S3 bucket policy for CloudTrail logs - Invalid resource

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail, pulumi

I am using Pulumi (Python) and trying to create a bucket for AWS CloudTrail logs. I based my code off [this](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/aws/cloudtrail/trail/#basic) example. I keep getting the following error: `Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource`

```py
import pulumi
import pulumi_aws as aws

# create a bucket to store CloudTrail logs
cloudtrail_bucket = aws.s3.Bucket("CloudTrailLogs")

# assign policy to bucket
aws_account_id = aws.get_caller_identity().account_id
bucket_policy = aws.s3.BucketPolicy(
    "CloudTrailLogsBucketPolicy",
    bucket=cloudtrail_bucket.id,
    policy=pulumi.Output.all(cloudtrail_bucket.id).apply(
        lambda bucket_id: f"""{{
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {{
                    "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20150319",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {{"Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"}},
                    "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_id}"
                }},
                {{
                    "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {{"Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"}},
                    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_id}/AWSLogs/{aws_account_id}/*",
                    "Condition": {{
                        "StringEquals": {{"s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"}}
                    }}
                }}
            ]
        }}
        """
    ),
)
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

My current environment is using the following:

```
pulumi==3.9.1
pulumi-aws==4.15.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the account ID without making it part of the apply/all statement.

Try this instead:

```
policy=pulumi.Output.all(cloudtrail_bucket.id, aws_account_id).apply(
        lambda args: f"""{{
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {{
                    "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20150319",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {{"Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"}},
                    "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{args[0]}"
                }},
                {{
                    "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {{"Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"}},
                    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{args[0]}/AWSLogs/{args[1]}/*",
                    "Condition": {{
                        "StringEquals": {{"s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"}}
                    }}
                }}
            ]
        }}
        """
    )
```